# Static array of chars with dynamic size

Tags: c++, variable-length-array

I'm creating static array of chars which size is defined runtime. And I'm not getting compilation errors.
 How is this possible?
Here is my example:

```cpp
void f(const string& val) {
    char valBuf[val.size() + 1]; strcpy(valBuf, val.c_str());
    cout << valBuf << endl;

  }

int main() {
    string str = "aaaa";
    f(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some compilers have this extension. If you compile in strict C++ mode, it should produce an error.

Comment: Variable length arrays are a c99 feature [but several compilers include it as an extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273829/does-int-size-10-yield-a-constant-expression), possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, this is normally only available in C99 and later.

Comment: If you don't need to change the string, you can use `const char *p = val.c_str();`

Comment: I've recently asked a couple of questions on VLAs: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24981392/1382251. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24989715/1382251. You might find their answers useful..

Comment: This is just a dummy example :) in my real code I'm changing array.

Comment: @Heghine: "Static array"? Where? I don't see any static arrays in the code you posted. Array `valBuf` is automatic (local), not static. If you attempt to make it static, then even an "extended" compiler will certainly complain. Static arrays are always required to have constant (compile-time) size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VLAs (i.e. variable length arrays)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are a feature of C99 which some C++ compilers ([GCC, for example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) support as an extension.

This is not allowed under standard C++.

Comment: And construction of the std::string from C-string. But C-string supported even without VLA. Isn't it?

Comment: Why would C strings depend on VLAs?  C strings have been in C since long before VLAs.